# How to build gradle again. Android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I created a github repo and imported my app into. I accidentally deleted some gradle files. Now I only have the /app folder. Is there a way to fix my project?

When I pull from github I only get the app folder.

Comment: Recovery the gradle files from the previous commits

Comment: I did pull prev commit but nothing changed.

Comment: When I import project from github, I get the app folder and readme.MD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project and imported all classes and dependencies from the old one to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

well thanks to android studio to have whats it called Local History

1. Goto your projects root directory and right click>Local History>Show history
   A window will pop up and you will be able to see the changes made with time stamp in the list at its left and change details at right side
2. select the particular version you want and click the revert button at the top left corner its a a u-turn type of arrow

if you are looking to recover a particular file you can just click on it and do the same above